# DolphinDB: The createAsofJoinEngine function fails to obtain data from the right table

Tags: join, streaming, dolphindb

The Asof Join Engine fails to obtain column data from the right table specified in metrics but succeeds in obtaining data from the left table. The metrics in my script is <[LogDateTime, TRANSACTION_SR401.LogDateTime, InstrumentID, Cont, LastPrice, MatchPrice]>. “Cont” and “MatchPrice” are from the right table and their cases are consistent with that of the input table.

The following is my DolphinDB script:

```
share streamTable(1:0, `InstrumentID`TradeDateTime`LimitUpPrice`LimitDownPrice`PreSettlePrice`SettlePrice`LastPrice`Volume`OpenInterest`PreOpenInterest`OpenPrice`HighPrice`LowPrice`Amount`BidPrice`BidVol`AskPrice`AskVol`LogDateTime, [SYMBOL,TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,INT,INT,INT,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,TIMESTAMP]) as EXCHANGE_SR401;

share streamTable(1:0, `UserNo`Sign`Cont`Direct`Offset`Hedge`OrderNo`MatchPrice`MatchQty`FeeCurrency`MatchFee`CoverProfit`MatchDateTime`AddOne`Deleted`MatchNo`UnderlyingID`LogDateTime, [INT,SYMBOL,SYMBOL,STRING,STRING,STRING,STRING,DOUBLE,INT,STRING,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,TIMESTAMP,STRING,STRING,STRING,SYMBOL,TIMESTAMP]) as TRANSACTION_SR401;

share streamTable(1:0, `Timestamp_result`Join_key`timestamp_future`timestamp_option`InstrumentID_future`InstrumentID_option`price_future`price_option, [TIMESTAMP,SYMBOL,TIMESTAMP,TIMESTAMP,SYMBOL,SYMBOL,DOUBLE,DOUBLE]) as PREV_MATCH_SR401;

createAsofJoinEngine(
        name=`aj1,
    leftTable=EXCHANGE_SR401,
    rightTable=TRANSACTION_SR401,
    outputTable=PREV_MATCH_SR401,
    metrics=<[LogDateTime,TRANSACTION_SR401.LogDateTime,InstrumentID,Cont,LastPrice,MatchPrice]>,
    matchingColumn=[[`InstrumentID],[`UnderlyingID]],
    timeColumn=`LogDateTime,
    useSystemTime=false
);

subscribeTable(
        tableName="EXCHANGE_SR401",
    actionName="joinLeft",
    offset=0,
    handler=appendForJoin{`aj1,true},
    msgAsTable=true,
    reconnect=true
);

subscribeTable(                                                           
    tableName="TRANSACTION_SR401",
    actionName="joinRight",
    offset=0,
    handler=appendForJoin{`aj1,false},
    msgAsTable=true,
    reconnect=true
);
```

The following is my sample data written by Python:

```
_exchange_record = {
        'InstrumentID': 'ZCE|F|SR|401', 
       'TradeDateTime': pd.Timestamp(2023,11,28,21,0,0,250000), 
       'LimitUpPrice': 1, 
       'LimitDownPrice': 1, 
       'PreSettlePrice': 1, 
        'SettlePrice': 1, 
        'LastPrice': 1, 
        'Volume': 1, 
        'OpenInterest': 1, 
        'PreOpenInterest': 1,
        'OpenPrice': 1, 
        'HighPrice': 1, 
        'LowPrice': 1, 
        'Amount': 1, 
        'BidPrice': 1, 
        'BidVol': 1, 
        'AskPrice': 1, 
        'AskVol': 1,
        'LogDateTime': pd.Timestamp(2023,11,28,21,0,0,290000)
    }
    _transaction_record = {
        "UserNo":'000001',
        "Sign": '#/ntjiw/.d',
        "Cont": 'ZCE|O|SR|401C6700',
        "Direct": 'S',
        "Offset": 'O',
        "Hedge": 'T',
        "OrderNo": '202311282100250000',
        "MatchPrice": 2,
        "MatchQty": 2,
        "FeeCurrency": 'CNY' ,
        "MatchFee": 3.1,
        "CoverProfit": 62,
        "MatchDateTime": pd.Timestamp(2023,11,28,21,0,0), 
        "AddOne": '' ,
        "Deleted": '' ,
        "MatchNo": '2023112821005700',
        "UnderlyingID": 'ZCE|F|SR|401', 
        'LogDateTime': pd.Timestamp(2023,11,28,21,0,0,291000)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Asof Join Engine joins each left table record with the most recent right table record before its timestamp. In your script, as the parameter delayedTime is not specified, a join operation is triggered when a right record arrives with a timestamp greater than or equal to the timestamp of the latest left record. However, with only 2 records in your sample, the left table record fails to match any right table record with an earlier timestamp. By adding more samples, such as adding “2023,11,28,21,0,0,280000” to “TRANSACTION_SR401.LogDateTime“, you’ll find that the definition of the asof join engine in your script is correct.